# Take div and insertAfter when div loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Building a site that gives play by play info for a game and want to insert a div after a specific div appears.

```
<div id="pbp-no-drive-0-0" class="no-drive">
  <span></span>
</div>
<div id="pbp-no-drive-0-1" class="no-drive">
  <span></span>
</div>
<div id="pbp-0-0" class="all-plays">
  <div class="drivesum></div>
  <div id="pbp-in-drive-0-3" class="play-in-drive">
</div>

<div id="pbp-no-drive-0-25" class="no-drive">
  <span></span>
</div>

<div id="pbp-0-1" class="all-plays">    
  <div class="drivesum"></div>      
</div>
```

The "no-drive" divs will appear first, the "all-plays" div appears after a drive has started. I'm attempting to insert the "no-drive" divs after "drivesum" divs if they are already not there. There are multiple "all-plays" and "no-drives". It is for american football and the "no-drives" represent special teams kicking off.

What would be the best way to handle this?

Comment: Knowing when the elements are inserted would be the best way to handle that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write up a conditional statement. If you are not sure when this would be appended, then you can have a timer in place.

```
var timer;

timer = setInterval(function() {   
    if( !$('.all-plays').find('.no-drive').length) {
       $('.no-drive').insertAfter('.drivesum');
       clearInterval(timer);
    } 
}, 100);
```

Comment: This works for the first instance, but successive "no-drive" divs don't insertAfter() "drivesum", tried removing clearInterval without success. Also, want to insertAfter the next instance of "all-plays". Would this involve using .next() or .closest()?

Comment: Most probably you would have to use `nextAll` along with first.. But it would make more sense to know when exactly the divs need to be appended and when they will be appearing in the `DOM`

Comment: I tried using $('.no-drive').nextAll('.drivesum').first() without success, I'll keep looking. Thank you for the input.

Comment: You have to give a specific selector.. `$('.no-drive')` will get you 2 of them initially.. SO it won't work..  Need to be something based on the index `$('.nodrive').eq(1).nextAll`

Comment: How exactly with the elements be appended to the `DOM`?

Comment: Through ajax calls, I'm only working on one half of the site. I focus more on the general layout of site, but we're way behind so I had to work on data as well.

Comment: We're using underscore for templates. Here is a link to the last update to live site. http://gotacoma.cstv.com/hi5gt/ if you click on "play-by-play" it shows what I'm working on.